# Windows 10 Crash, cannot boot

Tags: windows, crash, windows-10, boot, corrupt

So i have a challenge and question for you. My Windows 10 crashed itself yesterday evening with orange "bluescreen of death"(cursed be the guy or girl that designed cashing in Windows). I don't exactly remember the message but when laptop turned off... there was no longer detectable instance of Windows(cursed be the guy or girl designing boot part of Windows 10, only an idiot could do it like this).

Machine is Lenovo Y700 and Windows 10 x64. 
That was the problem description part.

My troubleshoot part begins now. NONE OF THESE WORKED

- I tried to check if that was hardware problem but all disks are detectable. Tried to reattach them. They all seem to be working fine.
- Tried to change from UEFI boot to Legacy boot.
- I created bootable repair USB and tried to chkdsk /r c:, nothing was corrupted there
- Tried BOOTREC /SCANOS, BOOTREC /FIXMBR, BOOTREC /FIXBOOT, BOOTREC /REBUILDBCD.
- Tried to automatic repair system. I knew it would not work as Windows troubleshoot tools are made by "dumb people" and they never work on Windows 10 but ok.(yes they are, in previous month my Windows 10 corrupted thanks to dumb system update cutting me from every program as they could not launch and menu start were frozen)
- Tried revert to previous compilation but it cannot detect Windows Bootable Manager most probably, so no luck.
- Cannot revert to base version as it does not see Windows at all.
- Tried to install new Windows on top of the old one but it does not detect anything about it, so i don't even have the fricking WINDOWS KEY AS IT IS BUILT IN WINDOWS INSTANCE... GRRRRR

Now i need somebody to help me fix detection of Windows instance, so i can do anything about it. Please help.

Comment: I think it is rather daring to name others with the i-word while not being able to find the correct place on SO...

Comment: I don't use it often. Sorry. Ignorant from my part. Though i thought it does include software in some sense as i need manipulation to get and fix Windows booting files. Will try on Super User.

Comment: Btw. please leave it on hold for few days as it is reference topic for Miscrosoft help research team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to remove the harddisk and conect is with an adapter to usb so it acts like an external drive, then install windows on it and place it back.
Or swap the disk in another laptop and do the same thing.
Or you could try to reinstall your bios (wich could cause even more headache)
Or perhaps your harddisk crashed and is not recoverable then replace your disk.
Or try to remove your RAM memory, perhaps that is corrupted..

Comment: I can try to install new Windows. It is not a problem but i will need my key. Will see about the ram actually as i remember what Win10 does with caching but it still should show some symptoms of ram problems, so not likely. Bios seems to be in order as i can use installation tools. Hard disk is detectable and has no bad sectors.

Comment: I think the key is stored inside of your bios chip so it will activate automaticly

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that it will work as it is different in each laptop model(right?). Though i also wanted to save my files without the need for clean install. I guess it may not be possible.

Comment: You can save data by connecting it as external harddrive, google for: sata to usb adapter

Comment: I know. Though i hoped to save time. Now i need a trip to the shop or will see if i can try to make it with bootable OS from usb. Also Win10 is on SSD.

Comment: Looks like my SSD died... have to double check that but eh.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, still weird that checkdisk was fine.. could you accept my answer with the check mark?